# Create a simple Login page using jsp and session

Tags: eclipse, jsp, session, tomcat, javabeans

I have created a simple login page in which user will give an username and password , and then it will be stored in session. After clicking on submit button it will show welcome user or the name. And if the user waits for few seconds then the session will expire and it automatically return back to the login page.

Here is my login page

```
<%@  page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" language="java" contentType="text/html;                      
charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><center>Give your login details</center></h1>
<form method="post" action="check.jsp">
Username:<input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<%=user.getUser() %>" >       <br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" size="20" value=<%=user.getPassword()   %> ><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

now in check.jsp i am doing my checking part for username and password

```
<%@  page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"  language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>login checking</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

 String USER=user.getUsername();
 int PASSWORD=user.getPassword();
 if(USER.equals("abhirup"))
 {
 if(PASSWORD==54321)
 {
     pageContext.forward("display.jsp");
 }
 else
 {
     out.println("Wrong password");
     pageContext.include("login.jsp");
 }
 pageContext.include("login.jsp");

 }



%>

</body>
</html>
```

and then finally i am displaying it in display.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" page language="java" contentType="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String title="Welcome : successful login";
out.println(title);%>
<h3><center>Your Name:Abhirup Parui</center></h3><br>
Username<%=user.getUsername()%><br>
<%session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20);
pageContext.include("login.jsp");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

and also this is my LoginUser.java file

```
package user;

public class LoginUser {
String username;
int password;

    public void setUsername(String value)
    {
            username=value;
    }
    public void setPassword(int value)
    {
        password=value;
    }
public String getUsername(){return username;}
public int getPassword(){return password;}

}
```

I am using Eclipse IDE and Tomcat server. Eclipse has shown not a single error in any of the pages but still when i run my login.jsp page.

[I am getting this error on running login.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIay5.jpg)

i have followed this [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp&ei=K2EKUq_kAoOXigfA94HoAg&usg=AFQjCNFfOnGl8L9UHoF7AHfdCFL790XmfA&sig2=aCiSX_9qIwz1Tw5jk270fg&bvm=bv.50500085,d.aGc)

please help me to find my errors.

**Update**

I can successfully run my login page. 
[I am getting this error now, but could not figure out where is the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfmLM.jpg)
[last part of the error is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzdnH.jpg)

how to fix these error . help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're trying to access login.jsp directly from the browser you have to move it out of the WEB-INF directory - files in WEB-INF are not publicly accessible.  If you move login.jsp up one directory and enter `http://localhost:8088/abhirup/login.jsp` in your browser it should pull up the page.  However, it is a fairly common practice to put jsp pages under WEB-INF/jsp or something similar and use a servlet to intercept and process requests and then have the servlet forward to the appropriate jsp page.

You have a syntax error on line 1, column 46 of display.jsp because you have the word `page` before your `language` declaration.  Change this:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" page language="java" contentType="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

to this:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" language="java" contentType="text/html;  charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

Comment: Yes it works. Can you please explain why jsp pages kept inside WEB-INF folder by default ?

Comment: People usually put jsp files in WEB-INF specifically so they aren't publicly accessible.  Servlets are exposed via a public URL defined in web.xml, so the request goes to a servlet, the servelet processes it and then it forwards to the request to a jsp page using something like `request.getRequestDispatcher("path/to/my/page").forward(request, response);`.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried the same code and I found some error in two JSP files

My login.jsp corrected code is as given below:

```
<%@  page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" language="java" contentType="text/html;                      
charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@  page import="user.LoginUser"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><center>Give your login details</center></h1>
<form method="post" action="check.jsp">
User name:<input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="<%=user.getUsername() %>"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="password" size="20" value="<%=user.getPassword()%>" ><br>
Submit <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Corrected check.jsp code is as follows:

```
<%@  page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"  language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@  page import="user.LoginUser"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty name="user" property="*"/> 
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login checking</title>
</head>
<body>
<%

String USER=user.getUsername();
String PASSWORD=user.getPassword();
if(USER.equals("admin"))
    {
if(PASSWORD.equals("admin"))
    {
pageContext.forward("display.jsp");
    }
else
    {
out.println("Wrong password");
pageContext.include("login.jsp");
    }
pageContext.include("login.jsp");
}
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Corrected display.jsp code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@  page import="user.LoginUser"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:useBean  id="user" class="user.LoginUser" scope="session" ></jsp:useBean>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String title="Welcome : Successful Login";
out.println(title);%>
<h3> <center> Your Name : Reneesh </center> </h3><br>
User name : <%=user.getUsername()%><br>
<%session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

My Java file LoginUser.java corrected code is as follows:

```
package user;

public class LoginUser {
String username;
String password;

public void setUsername(String value)
    {
        username=value;
    }

public void setPassword(String value)
    {
    password=value;
    }

public String getUsername()
    {
    return username;
    }

public String getPassword()
    {
    return password;
    }

 }
```

Kindly try with this code, I made some changes in the code by assigning String valuue for Password. I also used Eclipse juno IDE and Apache Tom Cat v 7.0 for running this Dynamic web project. Hope you will try and let me know if there is further error.

Comment: Please mark down the changes you made or post only that part of your answer which you changed. By this its difficult to makeout.

Comment: Gaurav I understood. Sorry I am new to stack overflow thats why it happened. From next post onwards I will take care of that. Thankz for making me clear.